# Logging in with either profile name or email in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a user bean with fields like userName, profileName, email etc.

I am implementing Spring Security in my application. In the login form I want the user to enter either profileName or email & he should be able to login with both. But it seems like the configuration only works for userName. I am fetching the user details from database using hibernate.
Below is my code

FormLogin.jsp

```
<form name='f' action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />"
        method='POST'>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Email/ProfileName</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='j_username' value=''>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type='password' name='j_password' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit"
                    value="submit" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'><input name="reset" type="reset" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </form>
```

loadByUserName method in CustomUserDetailsService class

```
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String name)throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException 
    {

        //returns the get(0) of the user list obtained from the db
        User domainUser = userDAO.getUser(name);
        logger.info("User fetched from database in loadUserByUsername method " + domainUser);

        Set<Roles> roles = domainUser.getRole();
        logger.info("roles of the user"+ roles);


        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
        for(Roles role:roles) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRole()));
            logger.info("role" +role+" role.getRole()"+(role.getRole()));
        }

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                domainUser.getName(),
                domainUser.getPassword(),
                domainUser.isEnabled(),
                domainUser.isAccountNonExpired(),
                domainUser.isCredentialsNonExpired(),
                domainUser.isAccountNonLocked(),
                authorities);
}
```

Query from the db

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public User getUser(String name){

        List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>(); 
        Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User u where u.name = :name");
        query.setParameter("name", name);
        userList = query.list();  
        if (userList.size() > 0)  
            return userList.get(0);  
        else  
            return null; 
    }
```

Can anyone help in fixing this?

spring-security.xml

```
<http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/forms/welcome*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <!-- Below config will display the custom form for authentication -->
        <form-login login-page="/forms/login" default-target-url="/forms/welcome"
            authentication-failure-url="/forms/loginfailed" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/forms/logout" />
    <!--    <http-basic /> -->
    </http> 


    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailService">
          </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't post your security configuration. I assume that you have setup a standard configuration with `DaoAuthenticationProvider` in place and you are already able to login with username.

I this particular case I see only one modification to allow login with either username or email. Add a `or` predicate to your hibernate query that queries for user by email too. I assume that your entity has a property `email`.

```
"from User u where u.name = :name or u.email = :name"
```

Comment: I've now added security configuration

Comment: great. nice to hear that.