# How do i make multiple logins for one account?

Tags: java, spring, security, model-view-controller

I make some website for myself(**I want to add it to my CV**) using Spring MVC, Security, and I have one question: I want to be able to login into my account using login OR email address, how do I accomplish this?

I have local database with users table that contains login,email and so on...

My Spring Security `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` configuration:

```
auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).usersByUsernameQuery("SELECT login,password,enabled from users where login = ?")
.authoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT login,role from users where login = ?");
```

So for example if I have users with **login:Test and email:Test@gmail.com** I want to be able to login using login Test, then logout and login via `Test@gmail.com`

Comment: One idea: `WHERE ? IN (login, email)`

Comment: Please refere to this topic : 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22879169/logging-in-with-either-profile-name-or-email-in-spring-security

Comment: Big thanks to tadman, it works!!!

Answer (score 0):

Check for `login` or `email`, e.g.

```
where ? in (login, email)
```

Related question:
[Logging in with either profile name or email in Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22879169/7335973)